# Problem with table (place in the center)

Tags: tables

```
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multirow}%
\modulolinenumbers[5]
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}
[c]{|c|l|c|c|c|c|}\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{A} & \multirow{2}{*}{Column 1} &
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Column 2}\\ \cline{3-4 }
&  & Subcolum 1 & Subcolumn 2 & \multirow{1}{*}{Problem}\\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{2} & Function & 1 &1
\\
& Function & 1 & 1
\\
& Function &1 & 1
\\\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{5} & Function &1  &1
\\
& Function & 1 & 1
\\
& Function & 1 & 1
\\\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{10} & Function & 1 & 1
\\
& Function & 1 &1
\\
& Function & 1  & 1
\\\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{20} & Function & 1  & 1
\\
& Function & 1 & 1
\\
& Function & 1 & 1
\\\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I have got a problem. The column named "Problem" is lower than columns "Column 0" and "Column 1". How can I place it in the center of the box? I guess this happens because "subcolumn 1 and 2" are placed lower and the next column follows them.

Here is picture[image]

Comment: Could you please add a fully compilable MWE?

Comment: @Raaja I added all packages I used if you meant that. I am sorry I am new to latex

Comment: Please also add your document class :)

Comment: @Raaja Thanks, my problem is already solved :)

Comment: If your problem is solved consider accepting the solution by clicking the tick-mark on the left-top screen near the vote button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have put the "Problem" on the wrong row. I see that after carefully examining the first two rows. Also, in the "main" rows, you forgot a `&`, therefore there is no vertical line at the end.

Solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}[c]{|c|l|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{A} & \multirow{2}{*}{Column 1} &
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Column 2} & \multirow{2}{*}{Problem}\\ \cline{3-4 }
&  & Subcolum 1 & Subcolumn 2 & \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{2} & Function & 1 &1 &\\
& Function & 1 & 1 &\\
& Function &1 & 1 &\\\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{5} & Function &1  &1 &\\
& Function & 1 & 1&\\
& Function & 1 & 1&\\\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{10} & Function & 1 & 1&\\
& Function & 1 &1&\\
& Function & 1  & 1&\\\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{20} & Function & 1  & 1&\\
& Function & 1 & 1&\\
& Function & 1 & 1&\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

The above code with better alignments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}[c]{|c|          l|                   c|             c|                       c|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{A} & \multirow{2}{*}{Column 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Column 2} & \multirow{2}{*}{Problem} \\ \cline{3-4}
                   &                           & Subcolum 1   & Subcolumn 2    &                          \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{2} & Function                  &       1      &        1       &                          \\
                   & Function                  &       1      &        1       &                          \\
                   & Function                  &       1      &        1       &                          \\\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{5} & Function                  &       1      &        1       &                          \\
                   & Function                  &       1      &        1       &                          \\
                   & Function                  &       1      &        1       &                          \\\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{10} & Function                 &       1      &        1       &                          \\
                   & Function                  &       1      &        1       &                          \\
                   & Function                  &       1      &        1       &                          \\\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{20} & Function                 &       1      &        1       &                          \\
                   & Function                  &       1      &        1       &                          \\
                   & Function                  &       1      &        1       &                          \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```